# Extracting values of a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have the following  dictionary within a list as I understand:

[{'week': 3, 'timing': '07:30'}, {'week': 4, 'timing': '20:30'},{},....]

I would like to extract timing and week and have them on separate lists. However, as there is a list on the outside there are no keys recognized. What I tried to do is the following:

```
for item in list:
    new_list =list( item.values() )[0]
```

But it shows an error because some of them are blank I think. Currently, I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range.
How can I extract them to two separate lists and have a NaN where they are blank?

Comment: You could just filter the empty lists first: `for d in list: if not d: continue; ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will help to extract the week and time value separately

````
check = [{'week': 3, 'timing': '07:30'}, {'week': 4, 'timing': '20:30'}]
week_list = []
timing_list=[]
for i in check:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k == 'week':
            week_list.append(v)
        else:
            timing_list.append(v)


Output
```[3, 4]
['07:30', '20:30']
````

Comment: The only thing I could question about this answer is that it doesn't take into account the position of the dictionaries in the list. So if you have empty/incomplete dictionaries, then their position wouldn't be respected and could provide some difficulty when further using the data in a dataframe, or analyzing it. Also, why do you use the `if` instead of appending by the `key`?

Answer (score 1):

You start by creating two lists and append the items. The iteration should be done over each object in the list, each object is the dictionary itself. Let's say the list that contains dictionaries is called `full_list`, because naming it `list` wouldn't be too convenient for python.

```
week_list = []
timing_list = []

for i in full_list:
   week_list.append(i['week'])
   timing_list.append(i['timing'])
```

If there are dictionaries with empty values, or empty dictionaries, or dictionaries with only `week` but no `timing` for example, I like to use:

```
import numpy as np
for i in full_list:
    try:
       week_list.append(i['week'])
    except KeyError:
       week_list.append(np.nan)
    try:
       timing_list.append(i['timing'])
    except KeyError:
        timing_list.append(np.nan)
```

This way you'll append a `NaN` value to your list whenever the key doesn't exist and that will prove helpful if you are later performing operations with the lists.

Full example:

```
full_list = [{'week': 3, 'timing': '07:30'}, {'week': 4, 'timing': '20:30'},{},{'week':4},{'timing':'09:21'},{}]
week_list = []
timing_list = []
import numpy as np
for i in full_list:
    try:
       week_list.append(i['week'])
    except KeyError:
       week_list.append(np.nan)
    try:
       timing_list.append(i['timing'])
    except KeyError:
        timing_list.append(np.nan)
print(week_list)
print(timing_list)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, nan, 4, nan, nan]
['07:30', '20:30', nan, nan, '09:21', nan]
```

### Edit:

If the dictionary was like the following:

```
full_dict = {'person_1':{'week': 3, 'timing': '07:30'},'person_2':{'week': 4, 'timing': '20:30'},'person_3':{}}
```

The iteration should be done per each `key`. Therefore the loop would be:

```
for i in full_dict.keys():
    and exactly the same code as before
```

Comment: i think the OP has dictionaryes where sometimes one or the other key:value pair is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, just for some reason it does not recognize the strings,neither timing nor week.

Comment: What do you mean with ti doesn't recognize? Are you getting an error? Could you provide more information to help you fix it?

Comment: @CeliusStingher now that I understood my problem a bit better I think your way is more safe. Thank you for your input. What would you add if you had keys? So you had for example: person1 and person 2 as keys and then for those two you have the week and the timing

Comment: I'll edit the answer so you can see it. But basically instead of iterating over the items in the list, we would have to iterate over each key. As simple as that

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to extract them separately.

```
weeks = [ a['week'] for a in new_list ]

timings = [ a['timing'] for a in new_list ]
```